# My function won't store the highest value in the variable in Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, foreach, var

I'm trying to get this field from my Mongodb, but I don't know why I get stored in my var only the first value (that isn't the highest) and the correct one.

```
 public function globalChartGet() {
  $firstInChart = 0;
  $users = User::all();
  foreach ($users as $user) {
      if ($user->points > $firstInChart) {
        $firstInChart = $user->points;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` in your code - is that a typo?

Comment: This is a typo. I close this below that :)

Comment: Is `$user->points` definitely an integer?

Comment: can you provide a sample data for User::all() ? Seems like it should work. Don't you miss a return statement ?

Comment: Im answring to thebluefox. Yes they are integers. To unex, it's simply a JSON that i get from the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this

```
$highest = $users->max('points');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Really really thanks. This is so simple yet so usefull. Maybe you'd know if some default method to order elements that i push in an array?

Comment: You can use laravel collection on Eloquaents or convert your arrays to collection.  This will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections